# A good and simple PDF reading

Tags: android, pdf, ubuntu

I need simple PDF reading software that synchronizes the "reading position" on my Android phone and my Linux computer – so I can continue reading on the other end where I left on the first.

I tested some software but they did not do what they promised or they make bad mistakes. Does anyone have any suggestions for my problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reading data"?

Comment: Excuse me. My English is a little bad. What I meant is that I want to read PDFs. And that when I open books on my cell phone or computer, I go straight to where I left off. Both on the computer and on the cell phone. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Might help if you could include what you've already tried (to avoid getting the very same recommended). I don't know which apps sync with a Linux counter-part, but you can find a selection of Android PDF readers [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf#group_110). I also have a list for [general eBook reader apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_ebookreaders) which often also support PDF. Sync often requires cloud services, that OK with you?

Comment: I try fbreader, FoxitReader and [Adobe](https://bit.ly/3jCr86d)

Comment: Amazon Kindle should do this. https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/email
https://itsfoss.com/kindle-linux-tips/